# Software for "remote whiteboard" that works on Linux and Mac OSX?

Tags: conferencing, whiteboard

I'm looking for teleconferencing software. While the audio (and video) are usually trivially solvable by Skype, I have problem finding software that would let me share "whiteboard" that all parties could write on, while teleconferencing.

The problem is - neither of us (people who will be teleconferencing) is using Windows - it's only Mac OSX and Linux environment.

Any tested solution that works? Preferably free, but purchase is not impossible.

Comment: Just wanted to through out the idea of a web based whiteboard.  This website has a few web options.  http://www.emergingedtech.com/2010/04/6-free-online-interactive-white-boards/  If there are some kind of privacy concerns or other restrictions, I can understand that.

Comment: I recommend Ziteboard (https://ziteboard.com) the online whiteboard with real-time communication. It runs in browser, no install needed, so it works with Mac and Linux as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Coccinella](http://thecoccinella.org/) is well-suited for this. Excerpt:

> Coccinella is a *free* and open-source *cross-platform* communication tool with a built-in *whiteboard* for improved collaboration with other people.
>
> …
>
> [image: ![Coccinella]]